# Regex to test number of dots in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I test whether a string contains 1 or more dots put together? Please show me where I went wrong in the code below.

```js
let text = "Is this .. all there is?";
let pattern = /[^\.+]/g; // do not allow more than one dot put together

// should return false but instead return true
let result = pattern.test(text);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Use this regex `/\.{2,}/g`

Quantifier `{}` represents the length two or more and you can only set string as inner HTML content not boolean like true or false directly.

```js
let text = "Is this .. all there is?";
let text2 = "Is this . all there is?";
let pattern =/\.{2,}/g;// use this regex
let result = pattern.test(text);
let result2 = pattern.test(text2);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `${text}'s result: ${result?"true":"false"}`;

document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = `${text2}'s result: ${result2?"true":"false"}`;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression is not right for your purpose. It matches a single character not present in the list: [^.+] (`.` or `+` character), then it will always return `true` if the string contains any character that is not `.` or `+`.

You could check if string contains more than one dot put together, using this pattern: `/\.\.+/g`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
let text = "Is this .. all there is?";
let pattern = /\.\.+/g;// check if there is more than one dot put together 
//should return true
let result = pattern.test(text)

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But I don't know why my solution is wrong: [^\.+] mean not allow more than one dot put tothether. Please explain why it is wrong. @Trung Duong

Comment: Who told you? [Your regex](https://regexper.com/#%5B%5E%5C.%2B%5D) means something else

Comment: @LinhChi You could check the explanation of your regex here https://regex101.com/r/x7mwRj/1. Literally, there was 1 main problem that make your regex doesn't work as expected: `^` inside square bracket only means matches `ANY ONE character NOT in the list`, it doesn't mean `NOT allow for the whole expression` inside bracket.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... How can I test whether a string contain 1 or more than one dot put together. ..."*

Use the `^` and `$` sytnax, signifying the start and end of line.

```js
var s = 'abc ... 123'
console.log(/^[^\.]+$/g.test(s))
```